# Ionic 2 catching errors when there is no network connection

Tags: angular, ionic2, connection

In my provider I make all the API calls, they look like this:

```
listSavedJobs() : Promise <any> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization':   localStorage.getItem('token') });

    return this.http.get(this.savedJobs, { headers:headers })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map(resJson => resJson)
    .toPromise().catch(function(error) {
        console.log (error)
    });

}
```

I've written a script to detect changes in the network

```
networkConnection(){
    try{
        console.log ('called network')
        this.network.onConnect().subscribe(data => {
            console.log( data)
        }, error => console.error(error));

        this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(data => {
            console.log( data)
            this.networkStatus()
        }, error => console.error(error));
    } catch(e){
        console.log ('network error' + JSON.stringify(e))
    }           
}


networkStatus(){
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Network Error ',
        message: 'No internet connectivity detected. Please try again.',
    });

    alert.present();
}
```

but when i try to call the networkConnection function in the catch, it throws undefined error. How do i solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netowrk detection should be automatic. You just need to subscribe for `onConnect` or `onDisconnect` at launch of your app. Following is the working code which handle the network connection and subscribe as per connection availability.

It automatically hide the message if internet resume.

**network.provider.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { Platform, IonicApp } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SharedProvider } from '../providers/shared.provider';
declare var Connection;
@Injectable()
export class NetworkProvider {
  onDevice: boolean;
  toastAlert: any;
  constructor(private _shared: SharedProvider, public platform: Platform, public ionicApp: IonicApp, private network: Network) {
    this.onDevice = this.platform.is('cordova');
  }
  startWatchingConnection() {

    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      let activePortal = this.ionicApp._toastPortal.getActive();
         if (!activePortal) {
          this.alertOffline();
         }
    });
    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
         let activePortal = this.ionicApp._toastPortal.getActive();
         if (activePortal) {
           activePortal.dismiss();
         }
    });
  }
  alertOffline() {
     this._shared.Toast.show('No Connection', null, 'bottom', true, 'Ok');
  } 
  isOnline(): boolean {
    console.log( this.network.type);
    if (this.onDevice && this.network.type) {
      return this.network.type !== Connection.NONE;
    } else {
      return navigator.onLine;
    }
  } 
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { NetworkProvider } from '../providers/network.provider';

constructor(platform: Platform, public network: NetworkProvider) {
    platform.ready().then(() => { 
         if (network.isOnline()) {
          network.startWatchingConnection();
        } else {
          network.alertOffline();
          network.startWatchingConnection();
        }
    });
}
```

`this._shared.Toast.show('No Connection', null, 'bottom', true, 'Ok')` calls-

```
public Toast = {
    show: (text: string, duration?, position?, closeButton?, btnText?) => {
      this._toastMsg = this._toastCtrl.create({
        message: text,
        duration: duration || closeButton ? null : 3000,
        position: position || 'top',
        showCloseButton: closeButton || false,
        closeButtonText: btnText || 'OK'
      });
      this._toastMsg.present();
    },
    hide() {
      this._toastMsg.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is : this.ionicApp._toastPortal.getActive();  I keep getting ._toastPortal does not exist on type ionicApp